# How can I solve the problem with fake/unwanted domain redirection?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

The problem is for some reason the website is accessible via fake/unwanted subdomains like:

```
whatever.example.com,
http://www.www.example.com,
ww2.example.com
blablala.example.com
```

The goal is to redirect from fake/unwanted subdomains to http://www.example.com using .htaccess
Every contribution would be fully appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to redirect to homepage or preserve path that was in "fake" request?

Comment: Redirect to the homepage, the website content should not be accessible via the fake domain. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```